# filling 2D Matrix in row major order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I tried to make a 2D array using list in python in this method:

```
N = 3
A = [[0]*N]*N 
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        A[i][j] = (i*N + j+1)
print (A)
```

The output was:

```
[[7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9]]
```

i wanted output like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you used `A = [[0]*N]*N`  to initialize A. This is a copy by reference method! This means that elements within A point to the same cell in memory and hence, when you assign a value to A, you assign that same value to multiple cells within A! More precisely, what happens within your code is that the final loop of i overrides all the previous written results with `[7 8 9]` and so you get `[[7,8,9], [7,8,9], [7,8,9]]` instead of `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]`.

Here is a fix, which initializes A without references:

```
N = 3
A = [[[0] for k in range(N)] for m in range(N)]
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        A[i][j] = (i*N + j+1)
print (A)
```

When initializing `A` using list comprehension as above, each cell within A points to a different place in memory and so the result is as you wished:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are creating list [0] *N and then placing it 3 times into another list

Running the code below will show how at each iteration if the loop all three lists are modified at the same time

```py
N = 3
A = [[0]*N]*N 
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        print(i*N +j +1)
        print(A)
        A[i][j] = (i*N +j +1)
print (A)
```

You could initialize it with a list comprehension instead

```py
N = 3
A = [[[0] for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        print(i*N +j +1)
        print(A)
        A[i][j] = (i*N +j +1)
print (A)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i knew something was wrong with the assignment of A. BTW why did you use my code twice?

Comment: No worries. Looks like my copy and paste went wrong! I have updated the second code block which should have used a list comprehension to initialize the list.